# 疯狂的 "crazy" meaning "unconventional"?

Tags: meaning

In English the word "crazy" apart from "being mentally ill" may have a less negative meaning of "being strange/weird/unconventional". Does chinese word 疯狂的 also have this connotation?
If not, what is the best chinese equivalent to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the terms 疯狂的(adv/adj); 疯狂(adj/adv); 狂(adj/adv) has other connotations beside being mentally ill.

> **recklessly** / **beyond imagination** / **out of the word (unrealistic)**
>
> Example:
>
> 疯狂的计划 / 疯狂计划 (crazy plan; reckless plan ; plan beyond imagination  )

~

> **uncontrollably** / **earnestly** / **enthusiastically**
>
> Example:
>
> 疯狂地殴打 / 狂殴 ( crazily beat someone; uncontrollably beat someone)
>
> 疯狂购物 / 狂购  (shop crazily ; shop uncontrollably; shop enthusiastically)

~

> **strange** / **weird**
>
> Example:
>
> 疯狂科学家 (crazy scientist/ weird scientist)